# Text box show value from Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using PHP, Ajax and Jquery, I'm able to create a cascading dependent drop down menu. But I want to have the third drop down to be a text box instead.

How can I do this?

[Ajax Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGD4Q.png)
PHP code...

```
<?php
    include('conn.php');
     $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM job_category group by category_name ");
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    ?>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
    Category:
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['category_num'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Sub-Category:
    <select name="sub_type" id="sub_type">
    </select>
    <br>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Priority:
   <select name="priority" id="priority_level" >

  </select>
 ?>
```

Please help, I'm having a hard time on this.

Comment: I don't see any code attempt. Are you looking to hire someone to do the work for you? The purpose of SO is to help guide you through, not do the work for you.

Comment: Jus want to know, how to apply it on a text box.

Comment: use jquery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)(http://api.jquery.com/val/) -> `$("#yourTextBox").val(yourAjaxValue);`, ie. `$("#priority_level").val(yourAjaxValue);`

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to do that using `<option>text here only</option>`, because that tag does not support `.innerHTML`. You'll have to not use a `<select>`, sorry. Everyone should learn that `<option>` just supports `.text` and `.value` and even if the Browser lets you put HTML inside that tag, in many cases, you won't be able to style it anyways.